# How do I return a clojure map with fixed keys and conditional values?

Tags: clojure, idioms

I have a function that returns a map. The keys are static, but the values are conditional. Like this:

```
(defn map-returning-function [x y]
  {:a (if (some-test-fn x)  "one value" "other value"
   :b (if (some-test-fn x)   15         25
   :c (if (different-test y) :one       :two})
```

Is there some more elegant way to achieve this without needing to write the `if` test for each value? The only other way I can think of is

```
(defn another-map-returning-function [x y]
  (if (some-test-fn x)
    {:a "one value",  :b 15, :c (if (different-test y) :one :two)}
    {:a "other value" :b 25, :c (if (different-test y) :one :two)}))
```

which doesn't seem much better to me since it repeats the key names for each branch of the conditional and it repeats of the function call on `different-test`. And heaven forbid that I need a `cond` instead of just an `if`.

Comment: you can certainly write some clever code that eliminates the if.... however is it really worth an extra indirection and/or complexity just to avoid typing three or four characters?? This may be a case where you should apply the KISS principle.

Comment: @mikera: I agree with you in this case but understand that I simplified the example a bit to make it clearer as part of a question. I was kinda hoping someone would bust out some mad macro'n skilz and show me how it's done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
(let [test-x (some-test x) test-y (some-test y)] 
  (conj 
    (if test-x {:a "one value" :b 15} {:a "other value" :b 25}) 
    (if test-y {:c :one} {:c :two})))
```

Conditions executed once and in one place, then used in another. Depends on context and personal preference though. Something more like your example may be cleaner:

```
(let [test-x (some-test x) test-y (some-test y)] 
  {:a (if test-x "one value" "other value")
   :b (if test-x 15 25)
   :c (if test-y :one :two)})
```

Comment: @stand, Assuming you are defining a lot of these conditional maps, I'd recommend writing a macro that generates the latter code in this answer. This would give the highest efficiency and highest readability. The macro would accept a list of quadruples, a key, test-fn, parameter, value if true, value if false.

Comment: Yeah, my current approach is just like your second example. I hadn't thought about using `conj` so I'll have to experiment with that (or possibly `merge`). I had a suspicion that a macro might be called for so I'm glad to hear @bmillare concur. Thinking through a generalized macro solution.

Comment: @stand It really depends on scope. I can imagine this could even lead to logic programming and a rule engine in some cases. :-) Macro is a step in this direction.

Answer (score 5):

Another variation one could think of is to use `merge`. One case serves as default, which is modified depending on the function arguments. This way you can easily group the tests and spice things up with some comments if necessary.

```
(defn map-returning-function
  [x y]
  (merge {:a "other value"
          :b 25
          :c :two}
         (when (some-test-fn x)
           {:a "one value"
            :b 15})
         (when (different-test y)
           {:c :one})))
```

Alternatively the other way around, depending on what you consider to be the default.

```
(defn map-returning-function
  [x y]
  (merge {:a "one value"
          :b 15
          :c :one}
         (when-not (some-test-fn x)
           {:a "other value"
            :b 25})
         (when-not (different-test y)
           {:c :two})))
```

Comment: Nice! I had thought of a similar approach but it's nice to see it implemented. I think this makes sense if there is a natural default map.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at what you're asking i'd say one way to do this would be constructing a function that looks something like this:

```
(pred-map 
  {:a [some-test-fn "one-value" "other-value"] 
   :b [some-test-fn 15 25] 
   :c [different-test :one :two]} 
  x 
  y)
```

where x is the argument to all references of first menti0oned function and y to the second one

a way to achieve this could be following:

```
(defn get-value [p tv fv a]
  (if (p a) tv fv))

(defn get-predicate-set [m]
  (set (map first (vals m))))

(defn get-arg-map [m args]
  (zipmap (get-predicate-set m) args))

(defn get-arg [p m args]
   ((get-arg-map m args) p)) 

(defn get-key-value-pair-creator [m args]
  (fn [[k [p tv fv]]]
    [k
     (get-value 
       p
       tv
       fv 
       (get-arg p m args))]))


(defn pred-map [m & args]
  (into {}
    (map 
      (get-key-value-pair-creator m args)
      m)))
```

These functions however rely on arguments being mapped to functions by equality (which seems to go with references) so it will not understand two equal anonymous functions as the same one.

if you don't mind repeating the arguments you create a simpler function looking like this:

```
(pred-map
  {:a [(some-test-fn x) "one value" "other-value"]
   :b [(some-test-fn x) 15 25]
   :c [(different-test y) :one :two]})
```

by following simple function:

```
(defn pred-map [m] (into {} (for [[k [p tv fv]] m] [k (if p tv fv)])))
```

or in pointfree style:

```
(def pred-map (comp (partial into {}) (partial map (fn [[k [p tv fv]]] [k (if p tv fv)]))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way of doing it :-)

```
(defmulti map-returning-function 
    (fn [x y] [ (some-test-fn x) (different-test y) ]))

(let [x-values {true  {:a "one value" :b 15}
                false {:a "other value" :b 25}}
      y-values {true {:c :one} false {:c :two}}]

  (defmethod map-returning-function [false false] [x y]
     (merge (x-values false) (y-values false)))

  (defmethod map-returning-function [true true] [x y]
     (merge (x-values true) (y-values true)))
...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code example seems most readable to me. Readability is often preferable over efficiency, unless you have a performance critical part of your code. But here's a way to only evaluate your conditionals once. I highly doubt that its performance makes much difference with your code. In terms of elegance I still prefer your first example, since it is clearer to see directly what the key-value pairs are.

```
(defn another-map-returning-function [x y]
  (let [first-map (if (some test-fn x) {:a "one value" :b 15}
                                       {:a "other value" :b 25})]
    (assoc first-map :c
                        (if (different-test y) :one :two))))
```

Answer (score 0):

By shamelessly stealing others ideas.

```
(defn map-returning-function [x y]
  (let [x-values  {true  {:a "one value" :b 15}
                   false {:a "other value" :b 25}}
        y-values  {true {:c :one} false {:c :two}}
        x-key     (some-test-fn x)
        y-key     (different-test y) ]
    (merge (x-values x-key) (y-values y-key))))
```